# jQuery validate doesn't work as expected. What could be a reason of it?

Tags: jquery

It is really strange situation.

I use jquery validation and looks like all code is correct but it doesn't work. 
No errors, no some message, simple nothing while other validation rules work well.

```
$("#MCFormWeb").validate({
    debug: true,

    rules: {
            MCFormTotalField: {
                  required: true,
                  number: true
        }
    }

});
```

I have all needed scripts loaded:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

It really has to work. What could be a trouble with it?

Comment: What doesn't Work? Does it always validate or never?

Comment: @PoulBak it doesn't validate at all this field. I can submit a form with empty field & no some error messages if I provide not numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a trouble.

In my input field I have had a `id=MCFormTotalField` but it wanted also `name=MCFormTotalField`.

It works now!